# VisualSVN version 2.5.1 shown wrong URL

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

We do use some repositories with several solution folders in the root/trunk folder. All VS 2010 solution files residing in one folder and all the projects in subfolders to the solution folder. Everything works fine as long as I do only check out the solutions folders in my working copy as the working copy root directory. After I have opened one of the solutions in my working copy, the visible VisualSVN URL will than be `https://.../trunk/SolutionFolder`. But, if I check out the complete trunk and open the same solution, VisualSVN will show up only `https://.../trunk` and all VisualSVN actions taken like "Commit", "Update", "Branch", ... etc. will use the trunk directory as the root directory for the action.

Has anybody experienced the behaviour and can anybody tell me how to avoid it?

Comment: Did you try to configure working copy root using VisualSVN | Set working copy root command?

Comment: Hi Ivan Zhakov, thank you, that worked. Obviously the initial working copy root detection failed when creating a new solution and folder when a parent directory already is a working copy root.